# why when the function is called. an extra rerender happens (React)

Tags: reactjs

see image please
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px7Mb.png)

when to write a call to useGetAppState() . so that there is no extra render

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import { RoutesSwitcher } from './app/containers/RoutesSwitcher';
import { useGetAppState } from './common/hooks';

import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  useGetAppState();

  return <RoutesSwitcher />;
};

export default App;
```

my component useGetAppState

```
export const useGetAppState = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useAPIHook<undefined, GetAppStateRes>({
    req: API.app.getState,
    enabled: true,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      dispatch(setAppState(response));
    },
  });
};
```

My component useAPIHook,My component useAPIHook,My component useAPIHook,My component useAPIHookMy component useAPIHook,My component useAPIHook,My component useAPIHook

```
export type APIArgs<T extends ((args: unknown) => unknown) | undefined> = T extends (args: unknown) => unknown
  ? Parameters<T>[0]
  : undefined;

export type APIReturn<T extends (args: unknown) => Promise<AxiosResponse<unknown>>> = ReturnType<T>;

type ReturnHookType<T, K> = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
  apiRequest: (args?: T) => Promise<AxiosResponse<K>>;
  data?: K;
  isFetched: boolean;
};

type Props<T, K> = {
  req: (args: T) => Promise<AxiosResponse<K>>;
  onError?: (error?: AxiosError | null | unknown) => void;
  onSuccess?: (args: K) => void;
  enabled?: boolean;
  apiArguments?: T;
};

export const useAPIHook = <T, K>({
  req,
  onSuccess,
  onError,
  enabled,
  apiArguments,
}: Props<T, K>): ReturnHookType<T, K> => {
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<K | undefined>(undefined);

  const apiRequest = async (args?: T) => {
    try {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      setIsFetched(true);
      const response = await req(args as T);
      const { data: responseData } = response;
      setData(responseData);
      if (onSuccess) onSuccess(responseData);
      setIsLoading(false);
      return response;
    } catch (error: AxiosError | unknown) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsError(true);
      if (onError) onError(error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enabled) {
      apiRequest(apiArguments);
    }
  }, [enabled]);

  // @ts-ignore
  return { isLoading, apiRequest, isError, data, isFetched };
};
```

Comment: can you try to call your api in useEffect(componentDidMount) hook

Comment: i tried it didn't work,

Comment: i get error, Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: `  useEffect(() => {
    useGetAppState();
  }, []);`

Comment: can you share the code which is inside of useAPIHook?

Comment: i am edit code , you can see

Comment: do you have any other idea ?

Comment: you shared the image and i am assuming that you are saying extra render by the extra calls but that is the preflight request that will made by browser for CORS so you don't need to worry about that. you can read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request here.

Comment: no, I should be worried because when I refresh the page it refreshes twice at once, which is wrong

Comment: useGetAppState has the extra render in the other components even though it is rendered only once in App.js, it maybe has the extra render by other else state rendering. Please check if the other states aren't caused the extra rendering after removing useGetAppState in that component

Comment: and how to solve the problem

Comment: do other states cause additional rendering, I removed and after that there is no additional render